# DOMContentLoaded only once

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon, addeventlistener

I'm using this code for firefox extension

```
1: var Test {
2:  f: function() {
3:    alert("DOM content loaded");
4:    window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Test.f(); }, false);
5:  }
6: }
7: window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Test.f(); }, false);
```

It should execute the code in function f() when DOM content (weg page) was loaded, it means it should give me one alert if I open new page or new tab or reload a page. The problem is, it gives me about 20 alerts, instead of one.
The problem is even worse if I want in function f() append to every anchor some text (e.g. if I want to append the text "(com)" it will append "(com)(com)(com)(com)(com)"

Do you know how to achieve the behaviour I want?
`removeEventListener` didn't help.

The culprit seems to be other firefox extensions and about:blank. Is it possible that my event listener on DOMContentLoaded ignores page loads causes by other  extensions?

thank you

Comment: In addition to the discussion going on in Wladimir's answer, which is great, you may want to avoid using `alert` for things like this, because it blocks until the user clicks OK. Maybe use `window.dump` instead.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I disabled the addons that were causing those problems and upgraded to firefox 4. I'm thinking about accepting his answer but I'm still a little interested if it's possible to listen only to DOMContentLoaded event caused by browser (not by other addons). Thank you for tip. I was looking for some better alternative than `alert`. Where can I see the output of `window.dump`?

Comment: In general, other addons shouldn't be firing DOMContentLoaded events, but frames/iframes inside of pages will be. You need to enable a config setting to use window.dump. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dump

Comment: They shouldn't but the links that were loaded "in the background" were in the database of one addon (alertbox - periodically checking for changes). They were in e.target.URL. Similarly some chrome:// windows and about:blank

Comment: I don't think this is directly related to your issue, but I do just want to point out that the `removeEventListener` call doesn't actually remove the event like you think it does. In both cases, you're passing in an anonymous function, but they aren't the _same_ anonymous function. JavaScript creates a new one each time they're defined. In order to remove the event listener for real, you need to save a reference to the function in a variable, and pass that variable into both the `add` and `remove` calls.

Answer (score 1):

DOMContentLoaded generally only fires once per document so I suspect that you are catching events from the page's frames as well. Impossible to tell for sure with the information provided.

I can tell why you fail to remove the listener however. `function(e) { Test.f(); }` is a closure, each time this code runs a new function is created. So the function you add as a listener is different from the function you remove. Try the following for example:

```
alert(function(e) { Test.f(); } == function(e) { Test.f(); });
```

To avoid this problem you need to actually remember your closure, e.g.:

```
var listener = function(e)
{
    window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", listener, false);
    Test.f();
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", listener, false);
```

Comment: @Wladimir Palent : Where to my code should I paste your code to test it?

Comment: You should paste it where you add the listener - and remove the attempt to remove the listener from `Test`.

Comment: @Wladimir. Do you mean paste your two snippets between the lines 6 and 7 in my code?

Comment: No, I mean to replace line 7 by the second snippet and remove line 4. The first snippet is only meant to exemplify what I said.

Comment: Now, the code is executed only for one page. When I reload other pages it's not. But I understand, that's because event listener was removed. So I added it again after `Test.f();` and I got again many alerts. I noticed though that those alerts are from more tabs. If I have only one tab open it's better, I get only two alerts when firefox starts and then it seems to be OK (so far). It seems that I need to modify HTML content in only focused tab (on DOMContentLoaded event).

Comment: As I said, you probably get DOMContentLoaded events from frames. You should check `event.target`.

Comment: e.target is sometimes `[object XPCNativeWrapper [object HTMLDocument]]`, sometimes [object HTMLDocument] and sometimes [object XULDocument] when I call `alert(e.target)` in listener() function.

Comment: `e.target.URL` will tell you the address of the document that loaded. I guess that one of them is `about:blank`.

Comment: I have only two tabs opened and those two URLs are alerted. Other 10 (approx.) alerts were about:blank and chrome://firebug or something similar. But I don't have other tabs opened that those two.

Comment: When I start browsing I get many many alerts with URLs that are not opened, as if it collided with other firefox extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test whether or not DOMContentLoaded is being triggered by a frame load or the main document load, and only execute your function in the latter case:

```
    var Test {
        f: function() {
            if (!event.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement) {
                alert("DOM content loaded");
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Test.f(); }, false);
```

Comment: I used `if (!e.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement) { ...` but when I enable extensions that problems still are there I'm testing `alert(e.target.URL);` I'm getting urls that is downloading the other extension.

Comment: Try it with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/alertbox/) extension, set some alerts in it and you will see.

Comment: So the problem is that you're getting alerts when windows are opening which don't contain normal web-pages (e.g. the extension install window)? If I've understood that correctly, you might want to try alert(e.originalTarget.defaultView) since I bet some are ChromeWindow objects and you could filter those types out.

Comment: The DOMContentLoaded from extension is of type `[object XrayWrapper [object Window]]` which is the same type as type when I reload normal content.